# Как вызвать java компилятор из кода

Tags: java, консоль, компиляция, javac

Хочу сделать свой блокнот-компилятор но как мне запускать код написанный в этом блокноте?
В этом чудо компиляторе будет консоль, по этому cmd не подходит
Java 11

Answer (score 0):

```
Process process = new  ProcessBuilder("c:\\jdk\\bin\\javac.exe "param1" ,"param2" ).start();
```

Только не понятно, что конкретно вам мешает использовать командную строку